# Objectify - How to declare a foreign key?

Tags: google-app-engine, foreign-keys, objectify, declare

I am working with Google app engine and Objectify. I am unable to find that how to declare foreign key in Objectify.

Any help would be really appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google App Engine datastore is not an RDBMS database, so the concept of the Foreign Key doesn't specifically exist. You can save a reference from an entity A to an entity B by having a Key property in A of B. For example consider the following:

```
@Entity
public class A {
    @Id Long id;
}

@Entity
public class B {
    @Id Long id;
    Key<A> referenceToA;
}
```

For more information about data modeling in GAE, take a look at:

- [Entity Relationships in JDO](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/jdo/relationships)
- [Modeling Entity Relationships](https://developers.google.com/appengine/articles/modeling)

Hope this helps!

Comment: Also, see https://code.google.com/p/objectify-appengine/wiki/Entities#Relationships

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what thanos said, you can store a reference to class A from class B by just storing the String/Long of the @Id of class A.  This has the advantage of saving space, but the disadvantage of type safety.  If you just use a Long then that can be the ID for any entity type in the data store and your cod must make sure it is used correctly, if you store the key you are storing the ID and the entity type, so you are less likely to have errors in your code.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do

```
@Entity
public class X {
    @Id Long key;
}

@Entity
public class Y {
    @Id Long key;
    @Index X x;
}
```

OR

```
@Entity
public class Y {
    @Id Long key;
    @Load @Parent @Index Ref<X> x;
    public User getX() { return this.x.get(); }
    public void setX(X value) { this.x= Ref.Create(value); }
}
```

**Note** : Never forget getter/setters (even for Id) as they determine what values come in the REST call that you make from client.